# Why there is an error in reading file in txt format?

Tags: java, readfile

```
static String[][] parseCSV(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    int fields;
    int lines;    

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\hp\\Documents\\Documents\\ID3ALGORITHM\\playtennis.txt"))) {
        String s = br.readLine();
        fields = 1;
        int index = 0;

        while ((index = s.indexOf(',', index) + 1) > 0)
            fields++;

        lines = 1;

        while (br.readLine() != null) 
            lines++;
    }
    String[][] data = new String[lines][fields];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\hp\\Documents\\Documents\\ID3ALGORITHM\\playtennis2.txt"));
    sc.useDelimiter("[,\n]");

    for (int l = 0; l < lines; l++)

        for (int f = 0; f < fields; f++)
            if (sc.hasNext())
                data[l][f] = sc.next();
            else
                error("Scan error in " + "playtennis2.txt" + " at " + l + ":" + f);

    sc.close();
    return data;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,IOException {
    if (args.length != 2)
        error("Expected 2 arguments: file names of training and test data");
    String[][] trainingData = parseCSV(args[0]);
    String[][] testData = parseCSV(args[1]);
    ID3ALGO classifier = new ID3ALGO();
    classifier.train(trainingData);
    classifier.printTree();
    classifier.classify(testData);         
}
```

> Received Error: Expected 2 arguments: file names of training and test data.

Why and what happens? The argument of `parseCSV` consists of two different files in the same folder and the system cannot read the file.

Comment: Whats parameters are you passing to the main method? Are you running your program from the command line?

Answer (score 2):

The error you mentioned is caused by the length of the main method `String[] args` been less than 2.

If you had written this program yourself you would've realized the file paths are passed into the main method from the command line.

I'll give you a quick example.

Simple Application.java file:

```
public class Application{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        if(args.length == 2) {

            System.out.println("2 args received");
        }

        System.out.println(args[0]);
        System.out.println(args[1]);

    }


}
```

1. Compilie on the command line using `javac Application.java`
2. Run program `java Application /root/dir1/dir2/file.txt /root/dir1/dir2/file2.txt`
3. `arg[0]` is now /root/dir1/dir2/file.txt
4. `arg[1]` is now /root/dir1/dir2/file.txt

Output:

```
2 args received
/root/dir1/dir2/file.txt
/root/dir1/dir2/file2.txt
```